# Select data items by id

Tags: javascript, angularjs, lodash

I want to return all fields depending on the gameId

I tried the code below but when i `console.log(vm.game.team1)` it returns an `undefined` whereas `console.log(vm.game)` returns only the gameId.

How can I get access to all the properties in game data.

```
"games": [
    {
      "id": 1016,
      "location": "North Laurel Comm. Center Ct. 5",
      "locationUrl": "url",
      "locationId": 1003,
      "team1": "Patapsco",
      "team1Id": 45,
      "team2": "Sharks-6th (Green)",
      "team2Id": 1,
      "team1Score": "20",
      "team2Score": "38",
      "time": "2013-12-06T18:00:00"
    }
]
```

my app:

```
 (function () {
     'use strict';

     angular.module('eliteApp').controller('GameCtrl', ['$stateParams','eliteApi', GameCtrl]);

     var data = eliteApi.getLeagueData();

     vm.game = _.find(data.games, {id: gameId});

     console.log(vm.game); // returns gameId
     console.log(vm.game.team1); // returns undefine
 })();
```

Comment: We do not know what your data looks like

Comment: I've just edit it.

Comment: Where do you get `gameId` from? You aren't setting this variable anywhere.

Comment: `gameId` is undefined

Comment: also where is your `GameCtrl` function ?

Comment: Why cant just do something like this? Pure object notation because it appears that `getLeaugeData()` returns an object. https://jsfiddle.net/h3nyekvm/1/

Comment: it is working without any problem , demo : http://plnkr.co/edit/Ex81o1aH0hEMoZJuxMzN?p=preview